Why we can't find the volume of cone by varying Slant height in integration?
To find the volume of a right circular cone, I assumed that :

The cone's base's centre is at the origin (0,0,0).
Cone is in the upright position.
It has a height of H. (In Y-axis)
Radius of R. (In X-axis)
Slant Height of L.
Angle $\theta$ from the vertical till slant height.

Element as a disk of:

radius r.
at $l$ slant height distance.
at h height from the vertex
thickness $dl$.(Along the slant height)
$Volume = \pi r^2 dl$.

Now,
$r = l\sin\theta$
So, $ Volume = \pi l^2 \sin^2\theta\space dl$
Now, Integrating this from $0$ to $L$.
$$ V = \int_0^L \pi l^2sin^2\theta\space dl$$
$$ V = \pi \space\ sin^2\theta  \int_0^L l^2 \space dl$$
$$ V = \pi \space\ sin^2\theta  \frac{L^3}{3}$$
$$ V = \frac{1}{3} \pi R^2 L  $$
(since, $L \sin\theta = R$)
But the volume must be $\frac{1}{3} \pi R^2 H$.
Why is this approach wrong?

The thickness of the disk between $\ell$ and  $\ell + d\ell$ along the slant isn't $d\ell$, it's $(H/L)d\ell = dh$.
If you just use Cavalieri's principle you don't have to introduce $\sin \theta$ only to have it cancel at the end.

The cross-sectional area of the cone will be a frustum of dl slant height, dh height and r+dr radius. If we use the volume of cylinder then how would it give us the correct volume of the cone?

@The The volume of the cone is the integral of the volumes of the frustra, each with volume $\pi r^2 dh$. The extra $dr$ in the radius and the extra length of the slant height contribute second order terms that do not affect the integral. That is preciseily what Cavalieri's principle says.
